# How to tar.gz recursively, but miss out certain folders

Tags: unix, shell

i have a directory structure with files like

```
/files/pics/gal1/1.jpg
/files/pics/gal1/thumbs/1.jpg
/files/pics/gal1/full/1.jpg
```

(with 1000's of files. gal1 and 1.jpg obviously change)

all i want to back up are everything apart from the ones in /full/. so basically, i need to backup:

```
/files/pics*
```

but exclude

```
/files/pics/*/full/*
```

how can i write a .tar.gz to do this?

thank you

Answer (score 4):

From the directory containing the `files` directory:

```
tar -zcf files.tgz files --exclude="files/pics/*/full"
```

Comment: Maybe: tar -zcf files.tgz files/pic/gal1 --exclude="files/pics/*/full"  to match OP's requirement